# Flutter application not lunched on real device

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I am trying to lunch my flutter application on my mobile but When I run

```
flutter run  --verbose
```

I got this error :

```
   +2 ms] Stopping app 'app.apk' on SM A315G.
[        ] executing: /mnt/SSDP/Sdk/android/platform-tools/adb -s RR8R107K94E shell am force-stop com.parsapp
[  +60 ms] executing: /mnt/SSDP/Sdk/android/platform-tools/adb -s RR8R107K94E shell pm list packages com.parsapp
[  +92 ms] Installing APK.
[   +2 ms] Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
[        ] executing: /mnt/SSDP/Sdk/android/platform-tools/adb -s RR8R107K94E install -t -r /mnt/SSDP/Project/Casp/mobileapplication/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk
[+5134 ms] Performing Streamed Install

           adb: failed to install /mnt/SSDP/Project/Casp/mobileapplication/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk:
[        ] Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk... (completed in 5.1s)
[   +1 ms] Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
[   +1 ms] Performing Streamed Install

           adb: failed to install /mnt/SSDP/Project/Casp/mobileapplication/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk:
[        ] Warning: Failed to install APK.
[        ] Error launching application on SM A315G.
[   +4 ms] "flutter run" took 36,587ms.
[   +3 ms]
```

In mobile developer Option

1. USB debugging is on
2. Verify apps over USB is on
3. Verify bytecode of debuggable apps is off
4. I have enough space (more than 100 gig free space)

and I choose **Transfer images**

When I choose **Transfer files** the lunch process remain in this level :

```
 [   +2 ms] Stopping app 'app.apk' on SM A315G.
[        ] executing: /mnt/SSDP/Sdk/android/platform-tools/adb -s RR8R107K94E shell am force-stop com.parsapp
[  +61 ms] executing: /mnt/SSDP/Sdk/android/platform-tools/adb -s RR8R107K94E shell pm list packages com.parsapp
[  +83 ms] Installing APK.
[   +2 ms] Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
[        ] executing: /mnt/SSDP/Sdk/android/platform-tools/adb -s RR8R107K94E install -t -r /mnt/SSDP/Project/Casp/mobileapplication/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk
```

But I can't lunch application on my mobile phone.

This is flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, 2.0.6, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
```

I am using FVM. And my mobile android version is 11.

When I run `adb install /mnt/SSDP/Project/Casp/mobileapplication/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk` stuck at **Performing Streamed Install**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fix the problem :

Run `flutter doctor -v` If you got `insufficient permissions for device` error you should this tricks:

1. According [official site](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device)

If you see an error message that says you're not in the plugdev group, you'll need to add yourself to the plugdev group:

```
sudo usermod -aG plugdev $LOGNAME
```

and then:

The android-sdk-platform-tools-common package contains a community-maintained default set of udev rules for Android devices. To install:

```
apt-get install android-sdk-platform-tools-common
```

2. If above tips not works [then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704636/insufficient-permissions-for-device-in-android-studio-workspace-running-in-opens):

   adb kill-server

and then start adb with super user or use sudo

```
sudo adb start-server
```

Done :-)

Answer (score 0):

you flutter channel is unknown .

> the version is unknown and seems to be on web developer mode so

if you are using it for android devices , it is better to switch to

```
flutter channel stable
```

after that

```
flutter upgrade
```

and then
`flutter run`

Comment: It's completely normal ,For that I did say I am using FVM @austin